# How to create a view that takes different row elements to separate columns, then filling data in (into such 2-dimensional table)?

Tags: mysql, sql

Table

```
+-+-+-+-+
|1|2|3|4|
+-+-+-+-+
|A|$|X|g|
+-+-+-+-+
|A|$|Y|d|
+-+-+-+-+
|B|%|X|w|
+-+-+-+-+
|B|%|Y|t|
+-+-+-+-+
```

View

```
+-+-+-+-+
|1|2|X|Y|
+-+-+-+-+
|A|$|g|d|
+-+-+-+-+
|B|%|w|t|
+-+-+-+-+
```

On MySQL, is it possible to create the view from the table, as shown above?

Extra: When it's not always only X and Y, it could be X,Y,Z,...
Is it possible to create dynamic loop to add as many columns to the right?

Comment: A view has a fixed number of columns, you can't define a view that will change automatically the number of columns depending on the values of the table. Also, you shouldn't want to have a view that does that, since it could break constantly the procedures that uses it

Comment: Thank you for getting back fast! 
What about if x y are fixed? Would this view be possible?

Comment: If they are fixed then it's a completely different question. It would be a simple view

Comment: Ok, thank you :) Sorry I'm quite new on SQL

Answer (score 0):

Not that it is necessary, but I am just curious, could you provide a use case where the original table schema and the subsequent view make sense? Surely there must be an easier way to organize your data?

Comment: use case: X, Y are survey questions. A $, B % is like submission ID. The table stacks up different answers.